# Symfony logging with monolog and snc redis bundle

Tags: symfony, monolog

How i use symfony monologging and snc redis bundle to store query and error log for a perticular client for the given time in my api .Any one have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Added the below settings in cofig.yml but nothing saved in redis.

snc_redis:

```
clients:

    monolog:

        type: predis

        alias: monolog

        dsn: redis://localhost/1

        logging: false

        options:

            connection_persistent: true

monolog:

    client: monolog

    key: monolog
```

monolog:

```
handlers:

    main:

        type: service

        id: snc_redis.monolog.handler

        level: debug
```